# Use Tab to switch from one contenteditable to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a function which searches and selects the following content of a division which is `contenteditable="true".`

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Headline:</td>
        <td><div class="editableDiv" contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Headline:</td>
        <td><div class="editableDiv" contenteditable="true"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I think the code should look like this but I probably used the `next()` selector in a wrong way:

```
$('table tr td .editableRow').click(function(){

$(this).next().dblclick();

});
```

Comment: There is an extra `();` in your `click` function

Comment: sorry copy+paste went wrong :)

Comment: Why do you exactly use the `click` function and `dblclick` trigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen for keydown on the editable element and check for character code `9` - this is the tab key. If so, move to the next item:

```
var $editableDiv = $('.editableDiv');
$editableDiv.keydown(function(e){
    if ( e.which === 9 ) {
        var $index = $editableDiv.index(this),
            $next = $editableDiv.eq($index+1);
        if ( $next.length ) {
            $next.focus();
        } else {
            $editableDiv.first().focus(); // cycle
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhEC3/2/

My example also cycles to the first `.editableDiv` if it has reached the end, if you don't want this, move the `e.preventDefault()` to only within the next focus block and remove the  cycle block, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhEC3/3/

Also, somewhat related: [Find next closest focusable element using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125842/find-next-closest-focusable-element-using-jquery)

Comment: Beatifully amazing :)